# The localStorage is not refreshing in Vuex

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I write codes with **Vuex** to login and logout in my Laravel single page application it's working well but when i login to an account the profiles information (name, address, Email, ...)doesn't show in profile but after i reload the page the profile information loads, and when another user try the profile the data of the last person that login shown to him/her

auth.js:

```
export function registerUser(credentials){
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        axios.post('./api/auth/register', credentials)
        .then(response => {
            res(response.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            rej('Somthing is wrong!!')
        })
    })
}

export function login(credentials){
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        axios.post('./api/auth/login', credentials)
        .then(response => {
            res(response.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            rej('The Email or password is incorrect!')
        })
    })
}

export function getLoggedinUser(){
    const userStr = localStorage.getItem('user');

    if(!userStr){
        return null
    }

    return JSON.parse(userStr);
}
```

store.js:

```
import {getLoggedinUser} from './partials/auth';
const user = getLoggedinUser();
export default {
    state: {
        currentUser: user,
        isLoggedIn: !!user,
        loading: false,
        auth_error: null,
        reg_error:null,
        registeredUser: null,
    },
    getters: {
        isLoading(state){
            return state.loading;
        },
        isLoggedin(state){
            return state.isLoggedin;
        },
        currentUser(state){
            return state.currentUser;
        },
        authError(state){
            return state.auth_error;
        },
        regError(state){
            return state.reg_error; 
        },
        registeredUser(state){
            return state.registeredUser; 
        },

    },
    mutations: {
        login(state){
            state.loading = true;
            state.auth_error = null;
        },
        loginSuccess(state, payload){
            state.auth_error = null;
            state.isLoggedin = true;
            state.loading = false;
            state.currentUser = Object.assign({}, payload.user, {token: payload.access_token});

            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.currentUser));
        },
        loginFailed(state, payload){
            state.loading = false; 
            state.auth_error = payload.error;
        },
        logout(state){
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
            state.isLoggedin = false;
            state.currentUser = null;
        },
        registerSuccess(state, payload){
            state.reg_error = null;
            state.registeredUser = payload.user;
        },
        registerFailed(state, payload){
            state.reg_error = payload.error;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        login(context){
            context.commit("login");
        },
    }
};
```

general.js:

```
export function initialize(store, router) {
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
        const currentUser = store.state.currentUser;

        if(requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
            next('/login');
        } else if(to.path == '/login' && currentUser) {
            next('/');
        } else {
            next();
        }

        if(to.path == '/register' && currentUser) {
            next('/');
        }

    });

    axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
        if (error.resposne.status == 401) {
            store.commit('logout');
            router.push('/login');
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    if (store.getters.currentUser) {
        setAuthorization(store.getters.currentUser.token);
    }
}

export function setAuthorization(token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`
}
```

I think that this issue is relate to my **localstorage**, how can i fix this?
I'm novice at the Vue and don't have any idea what is the problem.

Login Component:

```
<template>
<main>
    <form @submit.prevent="authenticate">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">

        <div class="small-10 small-offset-2 cell" v-if="registeredUser">
            <p class="alert success">Welcome {{registeredUser.name}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="small-10 small-offset-2 cell" v-if="authError">
            <p class="alert error">
                {{authError}}
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="small-2 cell">
            <label for="email" class="text-right middle">Email:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-10 cell">
             <input type="email" v-model="formLogin.email" placeholder="Email address">
        </div>


        <div class="small-2 cell">
            <label for="password" class="text-right middle">Password:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-10 cell">
             <input type="password" v-model="formLogin.password" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>

        <div class="small-10 small-offset-2 cell">
            <div class="gap"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button success expanded">
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>

</main>

</template>

<script>
import {login} from '../../partials/auth';
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            formLogin: {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        },
        error: null
        }
    },
    methods:{
        authenticate(){
            this.$store.dispatch('login');

        login(this.$data.formLogin)
            .then(res => {
                this.$store.commit("loginSuccess", res);
                this.$router.push({path: '/profile'});
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.$store.commit("loginFailed", {error});
            })
        }
    },
    computed:{
        authError(){
            return this.$store.getters.authError
        },
        registeredUser(){
            return this.$store.getters.registeredUser
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: where are you calling loginSuccess mutation to fill userdata?

Comment: im using this, in login component.

Comment: like @memic84 says, you shuld use vuex store as data storage. and to prevent data loose after reload pgae you can use vue-persistedstate and vuex-storwe will be stored in local storage by module itself. I hope help.  
`import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'` to require 
and `plugins: [createPersistedState()]` in new vuex config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.I have this code in my `EditProfile` component.

```
methods: {
            getAuthUser () {
                axios.get(`./api/auth/me`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.user = response.data
                })
            },
}
```

`this.user = response.data` is wrong, I changed to this:

```
getAuthUser () {
    this.user = this.$store.getters.currentUser
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Localstorage data is once loaded on page load, so when you use setItem, this won't be visible until the next time.

You should store the data to vuex store, and use that as the source. Only set and get the data from localstorage on page loads.

Otherwise use something like: https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate

Comment: Can you explain more on this example?